# NodeJS script to modify a JSON file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I need to write a NodeJS script for the following task:

I have a temp.json file with content like:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "id": "1.2.15"
}
```

When we run the script, I want the temp.json files content changed. Specifically, I want the number after the 2nd decimal in id to be incremented as follows:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "id": "1.2.16"
}
```

I don't know JavaScript and would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"use strict";

const fs = require('fs');

const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("file.json"));
const nums = data.id.split('.');
++nums[2];
data.id = nums.join('.');

fs.writeFileSync("file.json", JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
```

Comment: You don't need `JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("file.json"))`; you can just do `require('file.json')`.

Comment: @slikts, sure, however, if attempted to use in an ongoing script, `require()` only reads the file once, following calls return the result from cache. The cache can be deleted by `delete require.cache[require.resolve('file.json')]`.

Comment: @Freerey, this code answers the question.

Comment: Please explain your code. The OP clearly does not know javascript so a code-only answer like this is bad. We don't want to encourage people to copy/paste things on the internet without understanding them. See Vishnudev's deleted answer for how a good answer should look like

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to do it without breaking the async nature of Node, you can do it with the async functions as well:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('temp.json', 'utf8', (e, data) => {
  const obj = JSON.parse(data);
  const idParts = obj.id.split('.').map((el) => parseInt(el, 10))
  idParts[2] = idParts[2] + 1;
  obj.id = idParts.join('.');
  fs.writeFile('out.json', JSON.stringify(obj), (err) => {
     console.log(err || 'complete');
  });
});
```